# Greatly overlapping density distributions; however, the difference is statistically significant

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I am looking for the statistical significance of a difference between two groups (red and blue). Group sizes are equal (n = 4500). The distributions of these distributions overlap in a great deal as you can see on the plot, indicating no statistically significant difference.

However, the difference distribution is significant, **2.3 [95% CI: 0.4; 4.3]**, therefore it's statistically significant. Is used posterior_summary() function to calculate credible intervals. *https://rdrr.io/cran/brms/man/posterior_summary.html*

```
  ggplot(data, aes())+
  geom_density(aes(red), color = "red")+
  geom_density(aes(blue), color = "blue")+
  geom_density(aes(red-blue), color = "black") #difference between two groups
```

[image]

**Could you please confirm that my approach is correct?** (I am not doing anything wrong)

Comment: What test are you using to test this? How many units do you have in the samples?

Comment: Without knowing the details at least nothing of this looks wrong. If you have enough data points, these two distributions will indeed show up as significantly different.

Comment: I edited the initial post. N = 4500 for both groups (I use Bayesian regression posterior data).

Comment: Without disagreeing with any other comment, I note that there is a spike around zero for one group and not for the other group. That surely needs some thought and discussion. Also, I can't follow what you did at all clearly, as you seem to be mixing some unstated significance test, some unstated confidence interval procedure and a Bayesian approach,

Comment: @NickCox the spike around 0 is the difference between the groups that has been plotted

Comment: @MaartenPunt You're right and thanks. I don't use R routinely and was ignoring the code but that is explicit. Once you know that the colours are black and blue then it is also easy to follow.

Answer (score 3):

You are possibly mixing up significance and effect size. While the difference between these two distributions is small, the fact that you have large samples makes even such a small difference very unlikely to happen by chance, and therefore significant. This is all but unusual.